TDS Source Web Projects Displaying incorrectly
We are integrating the Sitecore Scheduled Publish module into our solution. Our setup requires importing the source code as an Existing Project in Visual Studio, so it can be deployed across all environments and developers. We downloaded the source for Sitecore 10.3, unblocked the files, added them to a dedicated namespace in our Foundation layer, and included the project in our solution. This follows the same approach we've used for other integrations.
We are using TDS 6.0.2 and rely on the TDS.Master project to include all code projects as "Source Web Project(s)." The Scheduled Publish project, like our other Foundation projects, is a .NET SDK-style project, but in TDS.Master, the project displays the full path to the project file (e.g., src/Foundation/ScheduledPublish/code/ScheduledPublish.csproj) instead of the project name. All other projects show just the name. We need consistency and for the project to display the name, not the path.
We've tried the following:

Auditing the solution (.sln), AssemblyInfo, csproj file, and TDS.Master scproj file for discrepancies—none found.
Cleaning, rebuilding, and restarting Visual Studio—no effect.
Re-adding the project—same issue persists.

Why is TDS "Source Web Project(s)" showing the path instead of the project name? Any insights would be appreciated.

Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange!!! Can you please share the link for sitecore publishing module you added to your solution in order to better understand the issue.

Sure, here is the link: SCScheduledPublishing

We put in a Sitecore Support ticket for this as well and they came back with some good information. Turns out all we needed to do was reorder the project and project folder in the .sln file. The picture below is after we changed the order (by just swapping them) and the project is now showing correctly in the "Source Web Project(s)" field in the TDS project properties.

